# How two create label column, based on index number (odd/even) on pySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Here's my Input

```
    index   date_id     year    month   day hour    minute
0   156454  20200801    2021    12       31    12       38
1   156454  20200801    2021    12       31    12       39
```

What I want is just make label 'poi1' for odd rows and 'poi2' for even rows

Here's my output

```
    index   date_id     year    month   day hour    minute  label
0   156454  20200801    2021    12       31    12       38  poi1
1   156454  20200801    2021    12       31    12       39  poi2
```

The pandas code is like this

```
df_movmnt_2["label"] = np.where(((df_movmnt_2.index)+1)%2 != 0, "poi1", "poi2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use when().otherwise()

```
   df.withColumn('label', when((col('index')+1)%2==0,'poi1').otherwise('poi2')).show()

+-----+-------+--------+-----+---+----+------+---+-----+
|index|date_id|    year|month|day|hour|minute| _8|label|
+-----+-------+--------+-----+---+----+------+---+-----+
|    0| 156454|20200801| 2021| 12|  31|    12| 38| poi2|
|    1| 156454|20200801| 2021| 12|  31|    12| 39| poi1|
+-----+-------+--------+-----+---+----+------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Why index 0 give output `poi2`, and Why index 1 give output `poi2` as well?

Comment: Me bad, forgot commas. This should work `df.withColumn('label', when((col('index')+1)%2==0,'poi1').otherwise('poi2')).show()`

Comment: OK, it answers the question accurately now